# Moving Windows 7 ProgramData folder after installation

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista

I need to move my `C:\ProgramData` folder in a Windows 7 installation to `D:\ProgramData`.

I understand how to make the symlinks and registry changes so this works.  My problem is that I'm unable to copy the files in the `ProgramData` folder because the OS seems to have some of them locked.

Specifically, the files in the `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` folder are blocking the move.

Am I out of luck here?  Is there any way to move the folder, create the symlink, and update the registry without any of the files in these folders being locked?

Comment: Aside from doing it off-line (i.e. remove the drive and do it on another machine), I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Could you expand on "doing it off-line"?  Right now I have 2 drives, an SSD that has win7 on it and a normal drive that has XP on it.  In other words, I can still boot into the XP drive and copy the ProgramData from the win7 drive onto the winXP drive without locking issues.

My question is: if I do this and go in and change the registry settings on 7, will I risk rendering the win7 installation useless?

Comment: See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/kb/949977

Answer (score 4):

[Move the Profile and ProgramData](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bCMHpr7ZA5k)

start from Windows 7 DVD and choose to repair Windows, open Command Prompt (CMD) and type:

> move the "Users" folder to the second partition by this command.

1. ROBOCOPY "C:\Users" "D:\Users" /COPYALL /MIR /XJ.

> move the "ProgramData" folder to the second partition by this command.

2. ROBOCOPY "C:\ProgramData" "D:\ProgramData" /E /COPYALL /MIR /XJ.

> delete the "Users" folder from C: partition.

3. RMDIR "C:\Users" /S /Q

> make Junction link to Profile folder in second partition.

4. MKLINK /J "C:\Users" "D:\Users"

> delete C:\ProgramData (ignore any failed massage)

5. RMDIR "C:\ProgramData" /S /Q

> open the Registry Editor and change the profile values to the new
>   path.

6. REGEDIT.

> navigate to this path: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE -SOFTWARE -Microsoft
>   -Windows NT -CurrentVersion -ProfileList and change the values to the new path.
>
> after windows restart open CMD as Administrator and delete
>   C:\ProgramData

7. RMDIR "C:\ProgramData" /S /Q

> make Junction link to ProgramData folder in second partition.

8. MKLINK /J "C:\ProgramData" "D:\ProgramData"

Answer (score 1):

Caveat: I've never done what you are asking before, but...

You can get easily get around the copy problem by down loading a Linux Live CD such as [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/download), and booting from it. You will be able to access your drive, and *copy* the folder from one location to the other.

When you reboot you can make the registry changes, reboot, and thereafter you ought to be able to delete the original.