# What is the right way to delete `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary`?

Tags: windows, msdn, help-files

The `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\HelpLibrary` takes 2.6 Gb. I can simply delete it as folder, but is it a good solution? Are there garantees that these files will not appreaed in future?

Searching in `Program and components` do not provide results like `HelpLibrary` or `MSDN` "program" nor any microsoft program with same size.

So should this fodler be deleted manually or there is some setting to move it away?

**P.S.**

The quesiton is very similar to [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/544042/is-it-possible-to-delete-c-programdata-microsoft-folder-without-breaking-prog) but I do not want to remove whole microsoft folder, only it `HelpLibrary` subfolder.

Comment: run VS, setup the help and remove all downloaded help content and select to always search in internet for help content

Comment: What exaclty I shuold run? I ahve only several `Microsoft Visual C++ YYYY Redistributable` in `Program and components` no any other Visual Studio setup components. :(

Comment: hm, normally this is the folder where the offline help is stored. make a backup of the folder (zip it and store the zip somewhere else), delete the content of the folder, and look if you have any issues the next days